# Unable to open IIS, It shows the following error "configuration section 'moduleProviders' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration"

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, windows-8.1, iis-8

I'm unable to open IIS. When ever I try to open, it shows the following popup error box as shown in screenshot. I have tried to google this but found no luck. I'm using windows 8.1.

[image: Error screenshot]

**Edit:**

There seems to be problem with some credentials in Administration.config file. I tried to read this to find the problem but I couldn't understand it. Can any one please tell me what seems to be the problem.

***Here is the content of the Administration.config:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.applicationHost">
        <section name="applicationPools" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="configHistory" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="customMetadata" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="listenerAdapters" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="log" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="serviceAutoStartProviders" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="sites" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="webLimits" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
    </sectionGroup>

    <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
        <section name="asp" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="caching" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <section name="cgi" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="defaultDocument" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <section name="directoryBrowse" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <section name="fastCgi" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="globalModules" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <section name="httpCompression" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="httpErrors" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <section name="httpLogging" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="httpProtocol" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <section name="httpRedirect" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <section name="httpTracing" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="isapiFilters" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="modules" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <section name="applicationInitialization" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <section name="odbcLogging" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <sectionGroup name="security">
            <section name="access" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="applicationDependencies" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <sectionGroup name="authentication">
                <section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                <section name="basicAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                <section name="clientCertificateMappingAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                <section name="digestAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                <section name="iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                <section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            </sectionGroup>
            <section name="authorization" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="dynamicIpSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="isapiCgiRestriction" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        </sectionGroup>
        <section name="serverRuntime" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="serverSideInclude" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="staticContent" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <sectionGroup name="tracing">
            <section name="traceFailedRequests" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="traceProviderDefinitions" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        </sectionGroup>
        <section name="urlCompression" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <section name="validation" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <sectionGroup name="webdav">
            <section name="globalSettings" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="authoring" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="authoringRules" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        </sectionGroup>
        <section name="webSocket" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="system.ftpServer">
        <section name="log" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
        <section name="firewallSupport" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
        <section name="caching" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
        <section name="providerDefinitions" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <sectionGroup name="security">
            <section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="authorization" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="authentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        </sectionGroup>
        <section name="serverRuntime" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<configProtectedData>
    <providers>
        <add name="IISWASOnlyRsaProvider" type="" description="Uses RsaCryptoServiceProvider to encrypt and decrypt" keyContainerName="iisWasKey" cspProviderName="" useMachineContainer="true" useOAEP="false" />
        <add name="AesProvider" type="Microsoft.ApplicationHost.AesProtectedConfigurationProvider" description="Uses an AES session key to encrypt and decrypt" keyContainerName="iisConfigurationKey" cspProviderName="" useOAEP="false" useMachineContainer="true" sessionKey="AQIAAA5mAAAApAAAmb4ap4w1j6K0E2K9da7Mr+ny+MigP94NVSxOH2yTYihGFA9vJoS0ap/LMnfM6k60qfjebgwsP8oNHw7gwc0cpfOnsKQNODerc7vagDg76RcqTscsmTpsJj1jSqgNQoew/6cTEgYdqUZFHI5sP8w43XqHUj+TQpgupTJyH0KQys/E/FlcstiBH23mypWeTGFB1HnH+k/l+OLssBg3mEfX01NdK9JeBjXrMHtrn6yvIU7AjBhUFkkOxJVSJEPeqRjKkG8+gP6UUBlLtfhmd8ChvLIqH789Pc2C2xwmgRjmy95uVnsoRVJXfdRqruooVjRoD0/ZlTsL5lBmKK842UgFYw==" />
        <add name="IISWASOnlyAesProvider" type="Microsoft.ApplicationHost.AesProtectedConfigurationProvider" description="Uses an AES session key to encrypt and decrypt" keyContainerName="iisWasKey" cspProviderName="" useOAEP="false" useMachineContainer="true" sessionKey="AQIAAA5mAAAApAAAqEGSB+6XCpv0q0+zKs/q2Wi8l8pP+L1rxeng4bOrO/rDo023wp7TfPmkoPA7lRXnsOks15z2kUIHOIM65X4PGBdzm9J89VP3TGWWgCf12jSJ9R8bLFnpGIvx/JNEELoFWVSHfF6BQoVZuk11mOGtpivUliOc0HaDZFYzXlw4IdaiJnKjxZbjrzfuEK4Be8SCYFg+0eVzgEj4TwG9Q2Gz0BtBi4NqmQFpZgE2benZwzmN3zc1sLyQGlL+fdJdyhxSJda7z5WuVWXi6YjOYTsECqjQsX6019VZikLw7FXYE0e4fkKccbhGT4NmlIxMIGtA6dtSdCNoh+ZOXIVTrbETXA==" />
    </providers>
</configProtectedData>

<system.applicationHost>

    <applicationPools>
        <add name="DefaultAppPool" />
        <add name="MVC" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />
        <applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
            <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="false" />
        </applicationPoolDefaults>
    </applicationPools>

    <customMetadata />

    <listenerAdapters>
        <add name="http" />
    </listenerAdapters>

    <log>
        <centralBinaryLogFile enabled="true" directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" />
        <centralW3CLogFile enabled="true" directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" />
    </log>

    <sites>
        <site name="Default Web Site" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
            </application>
            <application path="/MvcDemo1" applicationPool="DefaultAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MvcDemo1\MvcDemo1" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <siteDefaults>
            <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" />
            <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles" />
        </siteDefaults>
        <applicationDefaults applicationPool="DefaultAppPool" />
        <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
    </sites>

    <webLimits />

</system.applicationHost>

<system.webServer>

    <asp />
    <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
    </caching>
    <cgi />

    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
        <files>
            <add value="Default.htm" />
            <add value="Default.asp" />
            <add value="index.htm" />
            <add value="index.html" />
            <add value="iisstart.htm" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <fastCgi />

    <globalModules>
        <add name="UriCacheModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\cachuri.dll" />
        <add name="FileCacheModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\cachfile.dll" />
        <add name="TokenCacheModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\cachtokn.dll" />
        <add name="HttpCacheModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\cachhttp.dll" />
        <add name="StaticCompressionModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\compstat.dll" />
        <add name="DefaultDocumentModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\defdoc.dll" />
        <add name="DirectoryListingModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\dirlist.dll" />
        <add name="ProtocolSupportModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\protsup.dll" />
        <add name="StaticFileModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\static.dll" />
        <add name="AnonymousAuthenticationModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\authanon.dll" />
        <add name="RequestFilteringModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\modrqflt.dll" />
        <add name="CustomErrorModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\custerr.dll" />
        <add name="HttpLoggingModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\loghttp.dll" />
    </globalModules>

    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
        <add name="TRACEVerbHandler" path="*" verb="TRACE" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" />
        <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" />
        <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>

    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
        <staticTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>

    <httpErrors lockAttributes="allowAbsolutePathsWhenDelegated,defaultPath">
        <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="401.htm" />
        <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="403.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="404.htm" />
        <error statusCode="405" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="405.htm" />
        <error statusCode="406" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="406.htm" />
        <error statusCode="412" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="412.htm" />
        <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="500.htm" />
        <error statusCode="501" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="501.htm" />
        <error statusCode="502" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="502.htm" />
    </httpErrors>

    <httpLogging dontLog="false" />

    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <clear />
        </customHeaders>
        <redirectHeaders>
            <clear />
        </redirectHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <httpRedirect />
    <httpTracing />
    <isapiFilters />

    <modules>
        <add name="HttpCacheModule" lockItem="true" />
        <add name="StaticCompressionModule" lockItem="true" />
        <add name="DefaultDocumentModule" lockItem="true" />
        <add name="DirectoryListingModule" lockItem="true" />
        <add name="ProtocolSupportModule" lockItem="true" />
        <add name="StaticFileModule" lockItem="true" />
        <add name="AnonymousAuthenticationModule" lockItem="true" />
        <add name="RequestFilteringModule" lockItem="true" />
        <add name="CustomErrorModule" lockItem="true" />
        <add name="HttpLoggingModule" lockItem="true" />
    </modules>

    <odbcLogging />

    <security>
        <access sslFlags="None" />
        <applicationDependencies />
        <authentication>
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="IUSR" />
            <basicAuthentication />
            <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication />
            <digestAuthentication />
            <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication />
            <windowsAuthentication />
        </authentication>

        <authorization />
        <ipSecurity />
        <isapiCgiRestriction />
        <requestFiltering>
            <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true" />
            <verbs allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true" />
            <hiddenSegments applyToWebDAV="true">
                <add segment="web.config" />
            </hiddenSegments>
        </requestFiltering>

    </security>
    <serverRuntime />
    <serverSideInclude />
    <tracing>

        <traceFailedRequests />
        <traceProviderDefinitions />

    </tracing>
    <urlCompression />
    <validation />
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to some unknown issues, the administration.config file on your machine is corrupt. You should resolve that by running `inetmgr /reset`.

https://serverfault.com/questions/154091/is-there-a-command-line-parameter-for-inetmgr-exe-or-inetmgr6-exe-to-specify-the

Comment: Still facing same issue. I tried the command but it opens IIS and shows same error popup box.

Comment: @MudassirHussain then probably you need to update the question and post the content of administration.config.

Comment: Nope, you posted the wrong config, as it seems to be applicationHost.config. Can you double check?